# OpenEJB: can't specify global JNDI name

Tags: java, jndi, apache-tomee, openejb

I have app running on Tomee 1.7.2. (let's call it **myApp**)

**openejb-jar.xml** :

```
<openejb-jar>
  <properties>
     openejb.deploymentId.format = myApp/{ejbName}
     openejb.jndiname.format = {deploymentId}{interfaceType.annotationName}
  </properties>
</openejb-jar>
```

MyApp containts **MyEJB** ejb.

When I start tomee here is the **catalina.out** log:

```
INFO: ------------------------- myApp -> /
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb MyEJB: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=myApp/MyEJB)
INFO: Jndi(name=myApp/MyEJBLocalBean) --> Ejb(deployment-id=myApp/MyEJB)
INFO: Jndi(name=global/MyEJB!dao.MyEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=myApp/MyEJB)
INFO: Jndi(name=global/MyEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=myApp/MyEJB)
INFO: Created Ejb(deployment-id=app1/MyEJB, ejb-name=MyEJB, container=Default Stateless Container)
```

As you can see there are 3 Jndi names for one MyEJB:

- myApp/MyEJBLocalBean
- global/MyEJB!dao.MyEJB
- global/MyEJB

My question is:

Can I specify name of **global/MyEJB!dao.MyEJB** & **global/MyEJB** ??

For example: 
**global/MyEJB** -> **global/myApp/MyEJB**

Imagine case that you have 2 apps having each MyEJB ejb, both havign  global/MyEJB JNDI name :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Imagine case that you have 2 apps having each MyEJB ejb, both havign
>   global/MyEJB JNDI name :(

This should solve the issue - **{moduleId}**.

```
openejb.deploymentId.format = {moduleId}/{ejbName}
```